# Scroll position not working on linux mint, Chrome or Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I've read so many tutorials I am sick of them. I am trying to get how many pixels down the viewer is. I made this basic js script:

```js
var ScrollPos = document.body.scrollTop;

var intervalID = window.setInterval(CheckPage, 2000);

function CheckPage() {
    //alert(ScrollPos)
}
```

It sends me a alert every 2 seconds of the scroll position.
I tried:

```js
var ScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
var ScrollPos = window.scrollY;
var ScrollPos = document.querySelector(window);
var ScrollPos = document.documentElement.innerHTML.scrollTop;
```

None worked. I am running linux mint on chrome. It would be nice if it worked on every platform though.

Comment: What's wrong with theses solutions, do they always report 0? Are you sure these also don't work on other platforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues - first, you are setting ScrollPos outside of the interval, so it will only get set once, and will not update.  Second, you probably want to use `window.pageYOffset`:

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(CheckPage, 2000);

function CheckPage() {
    console.log(window.pageYOffset);
}
```